# Dynamic class creation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Is there an equivalent of selectors for classes?  How can I create a instance of a class from a string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want [`NSClassFromString`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString).

```
NSString *theClassForMe = @"NSMutableArray";
id newObject = [[NSClassFromString(theClassForMe) alloc] init];
```